# Rendering errors in JW Player (Transcoding done with avconv, streaming done by wowza)

Tags: mp4, h.264, jwplayer, wowza, avconv

I have problems with rendering errors in JW Player. They occur when I click play button and then click somewhere on progressbar to rewind stream (For example: I click play, then click on progressbar to skip 20 seconds of stream).

I would like to add that I am transcoding from MPEG2 in TS container to h264 in mp4 container.

Here is how i use avconv:

```
avconv -i input.ts -filter:v "yadif=0:-1:0, scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -g 90 -r 25 -bf 2 -s 1920x1080 -b:v 4000K -maxrate 4000K -minrate 4000K -bufsize 4000K -b:a 128K -c:a libvo_aacenc -f mp4 output.mp4
```

After transcoding, file is streamed by Wowza as HLS VOD service with default configuration file and watch it on JW Player

As far as I know, rendering errors may happen, when I start watching P or B-Frame and they don't when I start watching I-Frame. Is it possible for either Wowza or JW Player to wait for IDR Frame?

Edit: Files transcoded by VLC are working fine. I guess there is a problem with avconv. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/qdos2d2

Comment: It seems like this segment never finishes loading - http://85.237.160.244:1935/vod/mp4:KDN_odc_53_3M.mp4/media_w1259861224_0.ts

Comment: I have did another tests. It seems like Wowza's sample.mp4 is working fine, there must be a problem with my transcoded file. Still i dont have any idea how to fix it

Comment: How was it encoded originally?

Comment: Video: MPEG-2
Audio: MPEG-1
Container: MPEG2-TS

Comment: Shouldn't it be H.264?